Mark checkbox as checked is user already ha the role else keep it unchecked
Below is the component of the code.
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/services/api/api.service';
import {
  SNACKBAR_TYPES,
  SnackbarService,
} from 'src/app/services/snackbar/snackbar.service';
import { TokenService } from 'src/app/services/token/token.service';
import { DialogRef } from '@angular/cdk/dialog';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared/shared.module';
import { MatFormFieldModule } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatInputModule } from '@angular/material/input';
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogModule } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatProgressSpinnerModule } from '@angular/material/progress-spinner';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material/select';
import { MatAutocompleteModule } from '@angular/material/autocomplete';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatTableModule } from '@angular/material/table';
import { MatProgressBarModule } from '@angular/material/progress-bar';
import { WalletUser } from 'src/app/profile/profile.component';

export interface Pagination {
  pageIndex: number;
  pageSize: number;
  count: number;
  data: Role[];
}

export interface User {
  id: string;
  phone: string;
  name: string;
  isActive: boolean;
  jpAuthId: string;
  addedByName: string;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
  roles: Role[];
}
export interface Role {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  isActive: boolean;
  createdAt: string;
  updatedAt: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-manage-user-roles',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatTableModule,
    SharedModule,
    MatFormFieldModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatDialogModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatProgressSpinnerModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatAutocompleteModule,
    MatProgressBarModule,
  ],
  templateUrl: './manage-user-roles.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./manage-user-roles.component.scss'],
})
export class ManageUserRolesComponent {
  loading: boolean;
  isLoadingRoles!: boolean;
  userRoles: Role[] = [];
  pageSize: number = 10;
  pageIndex: number = 0;
  userId: string;
  availableRoles: BehaviorSubject<Role[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Role[]>([]);
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['name', 'actions'];
  roles: Role[] = [];
  rolesAssignedToUserHas: any;
  user: WalletUser | null = null;
  dataSource: MatTableDataSource<Role> = new MatTableDataSource<Role>();
  rolesUpdated: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor(
    private api: ApiService,
    private snackbar: SnackbarService,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public userData: User,
    private dialogRef: DialogRef
  ) {
    this.getUserRoles(this.pageSize, this.pageIndex);
    this.rolesAUserHas(this.userId);
  }

  getUserRoles(limit: number, offset: number) {
    this.api.get_roles((limit = 20), (offset = offset)).subscribe({
      next: (data: any) => {
        this.roles = data.data;
        console.log(this.roles, 'roles-------------------------->');
        this.dataSource.data = this.roles;
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.loading = false;
        let errMsg: string = error.error.message;
        switch (error.status) {
          case 403:
            errMsg = 'You are not allowed to perform this action.';
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
        this.snackbar.openSnackBar(
          'Error: ' + errMsg,
          'OK',
          5,
          SNACKBAR_TYPES.Danger
        );
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.loading = false;
      },
    });
  }

  closeDialog(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
  }

  rolesAUserHas(userId: string): void {
    userId = this.userData.id;
    this.api.getRolesAssignedToUser(userId).subscribe({
      next: (data: any) => {
        this.rolesAssignedToUserHas = data.data;
        console.log(
          this.rolesAssignedToUserHas,
          'roles a user has---------------------->'
        );
      },
      error: (error) => {
        this.loading = false;
        let errMsg: string = error.error.message;
        this.snackbar.openSnackBar(
          'Error: ' + errMsg,
          'OK',
          5,
          SNACKBAR_TYPES.Danger
        );
      },
      complete: () => {
        this.loading = false;
      },
    });
  }

  assignOrRevokeRole(roleId: string): void {
    this.toggleIsLoading();
    const hasRole = this.userData.roles.some((role) => role.id === roleId);
    if (hasRole) {
      this.revokeRole(roleId);
    } else {
      this.assignRole(roleId);
    }
  }

  assignRole(roleId: string): void {
    this.api
      .assignRole({
        userId: this.userData.id,
        roleId: roleId,
        status: false,
      })
      .subscribe({
        next: (res) => {
          console.log(res);
          this.toggleIsLoading();
          this.snackbar.openSnackBar(
            'Role assigned successfully',
            SNACKBAR_TYPES.Success
          );
          const role = this.roles.find((r) => r.id === roleId);
          if (role) {
            this.userData.roles.push(role);
          }
          this.rolesUpdated.emit();
        },
        error: (error) => {
          console.log(error);
          this.toggleIsLoading();
          this.snackbar.openSnackBar(
            'Error Assigning Role: ' + error.error.message.join('\n') ||
              error.message,
            'Close',
            3,
            SNACKBAR_TYPES.Danger
          );
        },
      });
  }

  revokeRole(roleId: string): void {
    this.api.revokeRole(roleId).subscribe({
      next: (res) => {
        console.log(res);
        this.toggleIsLoading();
        this.snackbar.openSnackBar(
          'Role revoked successfully',
          SNACKBAR_TYPES.Success
        );
        this.userData.roles = this.userData.roles.filter(
          (role) => role.id !== roleId
        );
        this.rolesUpdated.emit();
      },
      error: (error) => {
        console.log(error);
        this.toggleIsLoading();
        this.snackbar.openSnackBar(
          'Error Revoking Role: ' + error.error.message.join('\n') ||
            error.message,
          'Close',
          3,
          SNACKBAR_TYPES.Danger
        );
      },
    });
  }

  roleIsIncluded(roleId: string): boolean {
    return this.roles?.some((role) => role.id === roleId);
  }

  private toggleIsLoadingRoles(): void {
    this.isLoadingRoles = !this.isLoadingRoles;
  }

  private toggleIsLoading(): void {
    this.loading = !this.loading;
  }
}

Below is the template code of the component
<div class="p-5">
    <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-between center">
        <p mat-dialog-title class="!mb-4 !font-bold !text-[28px]">
            Manage User Roles
        </p>

        <button mat-icon-button mat-dialog-close><mat-icon>close</mat-icon></button>
    </div>
    <div mat-dialog-content>
        <div class="mt-4">
            <mat-progress-bar mode="indeterminate" *ngIf="isLoadingRoles"></mat-progress-bar>
            <!-- Roles Table -->
            <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="w-full table-auto bg-white dark:bg-night-700">
                <!-- Role Name Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef
                        class="text-xs uppercase text-gray-400 darfk:text-primary-300 py-3 text-left">
                        Role
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="darfk:text-white">
                        {{ row.name }}
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <!-- Actions Column -->
                <ng-container matColumnDef="actions">
                    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef
                        class="text-xs uppercase text-gray-400 dark:text-primary-300 text-right">
                        Assign Role
                    </th>
                    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row" class="dark:text-white">
                        <div class="relative flex flex-wrap items-center">
                            <input *ngIf="!loading" (change)="assignOrRevokeRole(row)"
                                class="relative w-12 h-6 transition-colors appearance-none cursor-pointer hover:ring-blue-400 after:hover:ring-blue-600 checked:hover:bg-blue-600 checked:hover:ring-blue-600 checked:after:hover:ring-blue-600 checked:focus:bg-blue-600 checked:focus:ring-blue-700 checked:after:focus:ring-blue-700 focus-visible:outline-none peer rounded-xl ring-2 ring-inset ring-blue-300 after:absolute after:top-0 after:left-0 after:h-6 after:w-6 after:rounded-full after:bg-white after:ring-2 after:ring-inset after:ring-blue-500 after:transition-all checked:bg-blue-600 checked:after:left-6 checked:after:bg-white checked:ring-blue-500 checked:after:ring-blue-500 disabled:cursor-not-allowed disabled:border-blue-200 disabled:after:ring-blue-300"
                                type="checkbox" [checked]="roleIsIncluded(row.id)" value="true" id="role" />
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </ng-container>

                <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
                <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns"
                    class="h-10 hover:bg-gray-100 dark:hover:bg-night-600"></tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <!-- <button mat-flat-button color="primary" type="submit" form="topup-form" class="w-full"><span
                *ngIf="!loading">Proceed</span>
            <mat-icon *ngIf="loading">
                <mat-progress-spinner mode="indeterminate" color="accent" diameter="18"></mat-progress-spinner>
            </mat-icon>
        </button> -->
    </div>
</div>

I want the checbox to be checked in the event that the user already have the role.
I tried checking for the roles the user has and comparing with the all roles and bind with the checkbox. I have also done extensive research to fix the issue to no avail.

Have you tried manually setting the checked property to "true" to see if it checks the checkboxes then? If it does, you might try assigning a static value to the [checked] attribute instead of a dynamic one that has to call a function.

Yes I added checked it works

You might try setting it to a property such as [checked]="row.isIncluded" and setting that isIncluded property before setting your datasource. Something like this.roles[0].isIncluded = false; right before this.dataSource.data = this.roles;. I'm not sure it would work, but it's worth a try.
